# Accessing HttpContext.Items from ViewComponent returns NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

We're following this official ASP.NET document: [Managing Application State](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state). In our one we controller we're setting a value for `HttpContext.Items[...]` and are trying to access that value from a [ViewComponent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components) that is called from corresponding View. But we are getting `HttpContext.Items[...]` as null inside `ViewComponent`.

**Controller:**

```
HttpContext.Items["TestVal"]= "some value";
```

**View:**

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("myVC")
```

**ViewComponent**:

```
public class myVCViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        String myVal= Http.Items["TestVal"].ToString(); //issue: Http.Items["TestVal"] is null at this line
        return View(items);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

In Controller section above, changed `Http.Items` to `HttpContext.Items` in the line at: `HttpContext.Items["TestVal"]= "some value";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Final update:**

I've tested simple case like as in your example, and this works well (on MVC Core v1.1.0).

So, it's hard to say why it's not working in your particular case.

However following our discussion in comments, you've found a source of the problem:

> I realised the issue is not related to ViewComponent; it's rather related to scope of HttpContext

**Orginal answer:**

In the documentation you could read:

> Its contents are discarded after each request. It is best used as a means of communicating between components or middleware that operate at different points in time during a request

and in section [Working with HttpContext.Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state#working-with-httpcontext-items):

> This collection is available from the start of an HttpRequest and is discarded at the end of each request.

and in [View Components documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components):

> Are overloaded on the signature rather than any details of the current HTTP request

Comment: I have deleted my original answer as I was wrong - Please find my update.

Comment: Per your request I've unmarked it. And, yes in the code I've `HttpContext.Items` instead of `Http.Items`. I've updated my post, as well.

Comment: The issue was related to what you had pointed out in your original response: `Its contents are discarded after each request`. What I was doing was that I have a Left Navigation menu that is populated  via another ViewComponent through another controller. When user clicks on a link on the left menu it calls another action in a different controller that sends info to its View that, in turn, calls another  ViewComponent. After you pointed me to the quotes from the referenced documents, I realized the issue is not related to ViewComponent; it's rather related to scope of HttpContext

Comment: Thank you, for explanation, it could be helpful for other devs.

Comment: Since my original answer was helpful, I have restored that part of my which was helpful. I hope this makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Getting HttpContext.Current isn't possible in ASP.NET Core. Accessing the current HTTP context from a separate class library is the type of messy architecture that ASP.NET Core tries to avoid.

But it's possible to get the context using IHttpContextAccessor from the ASP.NET Core dependency injection system like that:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public SomeClass(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
}
```

When the `HttpContextAccessor` will be injected then you can do something like that: `var context = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;`.